# Emitting sounds synchronously

Tags: java, android, audio

In my application, I animate an image and each time it reaches a certain point, I want to play a sound using a `MediaPlayer`. The sound is created with `sound=MediaPlayer.create` and started with `sound.start()`. My problem is that the sound is not always played : while it is usually correctly played, it is sometimes missing or shortened. This problem is seen with Android version 4.4 and not with 4.3.

At first, my sound was emitted from the UI thread. I then tried to manage it in a second thread, but without any improvement. What can I do?

Here is the code written in my dedicated thread :

```
private class EmitSound extends Thread implements OnCompletionListener,OnInfoListener,OnErrorListener{
    private MediaPlayer sound;
    private boolean killProcess=false;
    private Boolean emitSound=false;

    public EmitSound (){
        sound=MediaPlayer.create(myActivity,R.raw.sound);
        sound.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        sound.setOnInfoListener(this);
        sound.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }

    public void run(){
        while(!killProcess){
            synchronized(emitSound){
                if(emitSound){
                    Logger.getLogger("MyApp").log(Level.Info,"Sound started");

                    sound.start();

                    emitSound=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void EmitSound(){
        synchronized(emitSound){
            emitSound=true;
            Logger.getLogger("MyApp").log(Level.Info,"Demand");
        }
    }

    public void KillProcess(){
        sound.release();

        killProcess=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Logger.getLogger("MyApp").log(Level.INFO,"Sound finished");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        Logger.getLogger("MyApp").log(Level.INFO,"Info "+Integer.toString(what)+" / "+Integer.toString(extra));

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        Logger.getLogger("MyApp").log(Level.INFO,"Error "+Integer.toString(what)+" / "+Integer.toString(extra));

        return false;
    }
}
```

And when I want to emit a sound, I call `myProcess.EmitSound()` from a thread which is in charge of drawing into the `Canvas` of a `SurfaceView`.

I have added an`OnCompletionListener`, an `OnInfoListener` and an `OnErrorListener` to my thread plus logs for the emission of a demand and for the start of the sound and everything seems OK : a demand is made, the sound is started, the sound is completed and the cycle is restarted. I never get a call neither to my `onInfo` nor to my `onError` function but the sound is still sometimes not emitted. It really seems like the `MediaPlayer` is buggy...

Comment: Could you show us some code please ? there's no way telling what you're doing by just reading this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `SounPool` instead of a `MediaPlayer` solved my problem!